# ¿Cómo hago que las leyendas del gráfico tengan el orden que necesito?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, matplotlib, seaborn

estoy ingresando las leyendas que deseo para un countplot y me aparecen pero no en el mismo orden en el que las ingreso. El código es el siguiente:

```
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize":(12,10)})
sns.countplot(x = "Des_Per", hue = "Dieta", data = df)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.title("Recuento de Desórdenes Alimenticios según el Balance de la Dieta")
plt.ylabel("Recuento según el Balance de la Dieta")
plt.xlabel("Desórdenes Alimenticios")
plt.legend({"Poco Balanceada", "Buen Balance", "Deficiente", "Regular", "Perfectamente Balanceada"})
```

Y me aparece lo siguiente en la leyenda del gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No aparece en el orden en el que ingresé las leyendas.
También intenté cambiar el orden en el que aparece con el nombre de la leyenda que quiero, por ejemplo, "Poco Balanceada" en vez de "Regular" pero me da el mismo resultado.
¿Cómo puedo arreglarlas para que queden en el orden en el que lo ingreso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando un conjunto (`set`) como iterable que pasas a `plt.legend`:

```
plt.legend({"Poco Balanceada", ...})
           ^                      ^
           ^                      ^
```

Los conjuntos por definición son contenedores desordenados en los que sus items son únicos implementados mediante tablas hash. Cuando se itera un conjunto el orden es indeterminado:

```
>>> conj = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
>>> conj
{'a', 'c', 'b', 'd'}
```

`{objeto1, objeto2, ...}` es un literal para un conjunto, la otra forma es usar el builtin `set` y pasar un iterable cualquiera:

```
conj = set(("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Simplemente pasa un contenedor que si tenga orden intrínseco, como una lista o tupla:

```
plt.legend(
    ["Poco Balanceada", "Buen Balance", "Deficiente",
     "Regular", "Perfectamente Balanceada"]
     )
```

---

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║  Contenedor ║                     Literal                     ║ Builtin/class ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Lista       ║ [item1, item2, ..., itemN]                      ║ list()        ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Tupla       ║ (item1, item2, ..., itemN)                      ║ tuple()       ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Conjunto    ║ {item1, item2, ..., itemN}                      ║ set()         ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Diccionario ║ {key1: valor1, key2: valor2, ..., keyN: valorN} ║ dict()        ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: Me sirvió perfecto, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada Ximena, por cierto, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Saludos.